# External FEA confirmation

Tags: mechanical-engineering, finite-element-method

## The exact question

Assuming you have outsourced a FEA of a structural design (steel tubes and sheet metal, bolts and welds design):

What would you look for in the report to have confidence in the outsourced work findings

What questions would you ask them about it.

Is there anything that would set off a *red flag* that the outsourced work did a poor job or you would simply not trust their findings?

Comment: This looks like a "homework question" (and therefore should be closed,) but the most basic "red flag" would be that there is nothing in the report which states how they *validated* the FE model. The results from an unvalidated model are just a collection of pretty pictures - you might be able to sell them as a work of art, but they are worthless to use for engineering!

Comment: Last I was told, homework style questions were allowed on this site.  And no, it's not. My background is mechanical mechanism design and i've been asked to review a structures report, which is outside my area of expertise. Just looking for some pointers since it's been about 7 years since I've run an FEA.

Comment: You can send it to me and I can look at it pro-bono :)  Non-experts should not be trying to determine the strengths/flaws of a FE analysis.  However, if the results violate common sense that's typically a red flag suggesting a careful study of the report.